# Javasript :TypeError: input.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I need to filter the `li` based on the user's form input. Trying to implement a YouTube-like search bar that displays the video whose title matches the user's input. Used JS to assign the input value to a variable for which I get the error undefined value. Can someone tell me what is the mistake here?

```html
<div id="content">
  <nav>
    <form id="search" onkeyup="filter()" class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
  <div class="video-section-1">
    <ul id="list" class="row">
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/r&b.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">R & B -Beatpop</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```js
function filter() {
  var filterValue, input, ul, li, p, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filterValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("List");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if (p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: element with id `search` is form element not the input element

Comment: It is, otherwise the question makes no sense anymore and may be downvoted (plus, your answer can't be accepted). I'm reverting the edit that you did. (It shouldn't even have been approved in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to input element

```
<input id="search-text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

You are trying to get form element which does not have value which you are expecting. so its undefined. Thats why you need to get the search text from search input element.

there was also a typo for id: 'List'. it should "list" (with small letters) as you mentioned in html

```js
function filter() {
  var filterValue, input, ul, li, p, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search-text");
  filterValue = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("list");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if (p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <nav>
    <form id="search" onkeyup="filter()" class="form-inline">
      <input id="search-text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
  <div class="video-section-1">
    <ul id="list" class="row">
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/r&b.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">R & B -Beatpop</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine for me!

```js
function filter(field) {
  var filterValue, input, ul, li, p, i;
  filterValue = field.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("list");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    if (p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id="content">
  <nav>
    <form id="search"  class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" onkeyup="filter(this)" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </nav>
  <div class="video-section-1">
    <ul id="list" class="row">
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">Sorry, Apple THIS is the First Laptop with Mini-LED</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="column col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
          <video src="./Videos/r&b.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
          <p style="padding:5px;">R & B -Beatpop</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```